# Url as parameter gets intercepted

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, bad-request

In my asp.net mvc app I want to check if a certain url returns a valid response.
Therefor I send the url to a method that tests the HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

On my dev server (vs2008) it works just fine.
When deployed on production server however, it returns a Bad Request.
The method is never hit and my asp.net custom error pages are not used.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who ever read this in the future:
I remove the http:// part and used HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode to encode the path and put a route up that takes the last part as {*uri}.
This enables me to use a / in the parameter.

Then the checkUri I recreate the uri by adding the http:// and then check if the Host of this uri is the host I expected (in my example the request.url.host).

Then I make the httpwebrequest with the Uri I created and check the request for a response.

Comment: Seeing how it helped you out too, I figured I could accept my own response as answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are running into the [ValidateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.validaterequest.aspx) feature of ASP.NET? You can disable this for the page in question by modifying the first line in the aspx file to have the ValidateRequest="false" parameter.

Example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

You probably don't want to leave it in that state though, as the request validation helps prevent XSS attacks. Using HttpUtility.UrlEncode may also be worth trying, if you aren't already.